# Why is the web page html element (absolute xpath) dissapeared when downloaded as html file? what cause it?

Tags: html, xpath, web-inspector

### First, let's set up a code for full-xpath:

`(focus)` for `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div`

`(sub-focus)` for `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]`

### Tool to use:

1. Online Inspector: Chrome or Firefox (any of them will gives the same result)
2. Offline Inspector: any code-editor, I personally use Sublime-text
3. HTML prettifier to visually tidy up the downloaded html (optional)

### Cases

*piece of structure from non-downloaded html on the chrome browser web-inspecting tool*

```
▼<div class="BrandPageWrapper-liveAlertAd BrandPageWrapper-contentWrapper" role="main" id="MainContent Container"> = $0
<p id="MainContent" tabindex="-1"></p>
  ▼<div class="QuotePageBuilder-container">
    ►<div class="BadgeGroup-badgeGroup">...</div> (focus)
    ►<div class="QuotePageBuilder-row">...</div> (sub-focus)
    </div>
  </div>
►<div id="MobileAdhesion-Homepage" class="MobileAdhesion-container" data-module="mps-slot">.</div>
```

*piece of stucture from downloaded html on code-editor (cannot use chrome inspector, something prevent it to show the full content, preventing the user from scraping the data)*

```
▼<div class="BrandPageWrapper-liveAlertAd BrandPageWrapper-contentWrapper" role="main" id="MainContentContainer">
<p id="MainContent" tabindex="-1"></p>
  ▼<div class="QuotePageBuilder-container">
    ▼<div class="QuotePageBuilder-row">...</div> (sub-focus)
```

As you can see, the `(focus)` is missing from the html, If I tried to search the `BadgeGroup-badgeGroup class` in the html document, I gone zero result

### questions:

1. Why is it gone?
2. Where is it gone to?

### bonus-question:

In chrome browser Inspector search element plugin both `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]` and `/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/span[1]` pointing at the same element inside the `(sub-focus)`, why?

[source](https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/XAU=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly the HTML source of the web page does not contain the HTML concerned (the piece you describe as "gone" in the downloaded file), and it's actually generated in the browser by JavaScript.

Comment: `does not contain the HTML concerned` you mean h̶t̶m̶l̶ xpath ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking why your downloaded file doesn't contain the `<div class="BadgeGroup-badgeGroup">...</div>` element. My suggestion is that that element is actually generated dynamically, by JavaScript running in your browser. Downloading the page will save the raw HTML as served by the HTTP server, not the modified HTML which the browser displays.

Comment: so can be said, the `browser's web-inspector` is defect right? because when I `select-element > option > copy > full Xpath` the element in `(sub-focus)`, it giving me the "fake absolute xpath", which lead to the `bonus question`

Comment: No I don't think it's "defective" as such. It is an inspector of the dynamic HTML document in the browser. It's not an inspector of the HTML source, and it generates an XPath that selects a particular element in the context of the dynamic HTML document. If you want an XPath that will select the element in the static HTML page, you should disable JavaScript in your browser, refresh the page, and _then_ use the web inspector.

Comment: I see, from what I understand, is that when the `JavaScript is ON`, the element that I want can have `2 xpath address`, which is why if I want to use the original element, I have to turn off the JavaScript, correct?

Comment: with this, all the questions have been answered, including the bonus one. thank you sir Conal.

Comment: If JavaScript is turned on, then it can change the content of the page, and if the page content changes, then the address of a given element may also change. For instance, if a new `div` element is created _before_ an existing `div`, then the existing `div` which might have been `div[1]` will become `div[2]`, etc.